# C# String.Format with '{' character

Tags: c#

Can we do a String.Format in a string that contains the '{' character?

Example: `String.Format("a{a}a {0} bbb {1}", "val1", "val2");`

The a{a}a should be interpreted as part of the string, not as a formatter...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Warning: "val2" is never used.

Comment: It was a typo, I meant to write {1}.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use: `{{`. By the way, this is answerable from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx):

> To specify a single literal brace character in format, specify two leading or trailing brace characters; that is, "`{{`" or "`}}`".

Comment: `{{{`? What do you mean? The escape is `{{`.

Comment: @Kendall Frey: It was a typo.

Answer (score 12):

Yes.  Use two `{`s, like this:

```
String.Format("a{{a}}a {0} bbb {1}", "val1", "val2");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should escape { and } with {{ and }}